# Why "uninitialized constant" error when using has_many association collection (model ending with s bug)?

Tags: methods, ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I can't find why I get the following error in my view when using any method that has_many provides to its collection (such as 'where') :

NameError in History/hist_paquets_mesures#show
Showing /var/www-opf/opf/app/views/history/hist_paquets_mesures/show.html.haml where line #19 raised: 
**uninitialized constant HistPaquetMesures::HistVersionsPaquetsMesure**

The part of my (HAML) view causing this issue :

```
// I want to make this work
//= @hist_paquet_mesures.hist_versions_paquets_mesures.where(:hist_origine_modification == nil).first.version
// So I debug with this, which is causing the same error
= debug @hist_paquet_mesures.hist_versions_paquets_mesures
```

I set up an exception for the special singular-plural names that I use in **config/initializers/inflections.rb** :

```
  ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
    inflect.irregular 'pub_liste_horizon', 'pub_listes_horizon'
    inflect.irregular 'hist_paquet_mesures', 'hist_paquets_mesures'
    inflect.irregular 'hist_projet_connexe', 'hist_projets_connexes'
    inflect.irregular 'hist_version_paquet_mesures', 'hist_versions_paquets_mesures'
    inflect.irregular 'hist_origine_modification', 'hist_origines_modification'
  end
```

**Pluralize** , **singularize** and **classify** methods are working as expected on rails console :

```
"hist_versions_paquets_mesures".singularize  => "hist_version_paquet_mesures"
"hist_versions_paquets_mesures".classify  => "HistVersionPaquetMesures"
"hist_version_paquet_mesures".pluralize  => "hist_versions_paquets_mesures"
```

My **app/model/hist_paquet_mesures.rb** model :

```
class HistPaquetMesures < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pub_indice
  belongs_to :pub_liste_horizon
  belongs_to :admin_utilisateur
  has_many :hist_versions_paquets_mesures
end
```

My **app/model/hist_version_paquet_mesures.rb** model :

```
class HistVersionPaquetMesures < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hist_paquet_mesures
  belongs_to :pub_modification
  belongs_to :vers_origine, :class_name => 'HistOrigineModification', :foreign_key => 'hist_origine_modification_id'
  # polymorphic association
  has_one :comme_origine, :class_name => 'HistOrigineModification', as: :hist_origine
end
```

My **app/controllers/history/hist_paquets_mesures_controller.rb** controller :

```
class History::HistPaquetsMesuresController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @hist_paquet_mesures = HistPaquetMesures.find_by_id(params[:id])
    respond_with(:history, @hist_paquet_mesures)
  end
end
```

The weird thing is where the "s" go in "HistVersionsPaquetsMesure" of the error message : **HistPaquetMesures::HistVersionsPaquetsMesure**

Shouldn't it be HistPaquetMesures::HistVersionPaquetMesures ?
Why do I have this result ?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a BUG !

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8928) on this case.
It seems the problem comes from ActiveSupport library.
To get the class name it performs a "camelize.singularize". As my inflections are defined with underscore, the expected result is incorrect. It would have worked if the library had performed a "singularize.camelize".

Workaround : add another irregular inflection with camelized syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :class_name parameter in:

```
has_many :hist_versions_paquets_mesures, :class_name => HistVersionPaquetMesures
```

you maybe have a problem with your associations' name.

Comment: Indeed your solution si working. Thanks. Why is that happening. Where could I have a problem in my association name ?

Comment: I think that you should not use plural for your models' name. I would name my models like this: _HistPaquetMesure_, _HistVersionPaquetMesure_, and use **has_many** association like this in my _HistPaquetMesure_ model : `has_many :hist_version_paquet_mesures`. But I don't know what you're doing reference, with these models' name, so maybe you wouldn't change them.

Comment: I will follow you advice though it is not syntactically correct in french. A record of my table is talking about "a packet holding many measures" the plural form in french would be "many packets holding many measures". Many Thanks

Comment: You can give me your tables' name. I'm french, so I may help you.

Comment: And why my association is working in the opposite direction (belongs_to) ? Ex : my_hist_version_paquet_mesures.hist_paquet_mesures

Comment: My tables names are : hist_paquets_mesures and hist_versions_paquets_mesures

Comment: So I would name my model like this: _HistPaquetsMesure_, _HistVersionsPaquetsMesure_ and use has_many association like this in my HistPaquetsMesure model : has_many :hist_versions_paquets_mesures. For the belongs to relation I would change **belongs_to :hist_paquet_mesures** in **belongs_to :hist_paquets_mesure** . It was working for your belongs_to association because, your model was named with a plural and your association name was a model's name.